# Error installing WSUS in windows server 2012

Tags: windows, installation, wsus

I can´t install WSUS in windows server 2012, when i finished to install and start the post installation tasks, show a irrecuperable error, "the object name 'SUSDB.dbo.tbSchemaVersion' is not valid".

Answer (score 1):

I guess there was a problem with Database creation.
Can you uninstall WSUS, delete the Database, and start from scratch, this usually helps.